# Is "allergic" a misnomer?

Tags: adjectives

**-ergic** as in sentences like *Y is Xergic* denotes that Y has the property of being sensitive to X or that Y produces X. In simple terms, it means that the noun does something with x. In my field of study, this os true for e.g. dopaminergic-, serotonergic-, and glutamatergic neurons which are neurons that are sensitive to these respective neurotransmitters and/or releases them.

But the word **allergic** seems to denote only a sensitivity to allergens but not a production of allergens? An allergic person does not release pollen. Is the word allergic too general and therefore a misnomer?

Comment: The word *allergic* was first by around 20 years (1911). If anybody is misusing the suffix, it's your field of study, which adapted the *-ergic* suffix in 1934. [From the OED: H.H. Dale – *We seem to need words which will briefly indicate action by two kinds of chemical transmission, due in the one case to some substance like adrenaline, in the other case to a substance like acetylcholine, so that we may distinguish between chemical function and anatomical origin. I suggest the words ‘adrenergic’ and ‘cholinergic’ respectively.*]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The etymology of the term is different from what you are suggesting, I don't think it is a misnomer:

[Allergic](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=allergic) (adj.) :

> - 1911, ***from allergy + -[ic](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=-ic&allowed_in_frame=0);*** perhaps modeled on French allergique (1906).

***allergy (n.)*** :

> - 1911, ***from German Allergie***, coined 1906 by Austrian pediatrician Clemens E. von Pirquet (1874-1929) ***from Greek allos "other, different, strange" (see alias (adv.)) + ergon "activity" (see organ).***

***[Dopaminergic](https://en.m.wiktionary.org/wiki/dopaminergic):***

> - Containing, involving, or transmitting dopamine.

Etymology:

> - dopamine +‎ [-ergic](https://en.m.wiktionary.org/wiki/-ergic#English)

***-ergic***

> - produced by the specified thing
> - activated by the specified thing

Comment: The etymology is not that different. The suffix *-ergic* comes from the Greek suffix *-ergos* + the English/French/Latin suffix *-ic*. These are the same components that form *allergic* (since *-ergos* is the suffix corresponding to the Greek word *ergon*.